# Primefaces Tag <p:organigram> doesn't work

Tags: maven, jsf, primefaces

The error: `HTTP Status 500 - /organigram.xhtml @12,15 <p:organigram> Tag Library supports namespace: http://primefaces.org/ui, but no tag was defined for name: organigram`

The scenario is: I'm using Primefaces 6.1 version, the component needs at least [v6.0.8](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/organigram.xhtml) version.

I'm using Ultima Theme too.

Follows the PrimeFaces dependency.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>6.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <!-- For 3.5 and older -->
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

**organigram.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" template="/WEB-INF/template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="content">

        <p:organigram></p:organigram>

    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

Independent of putting something in the component, it returns the same error

**Build Path**

[image: Build Path]

**Maven Dependency**

[image: Maven Dependecy]

**template.xhtml**

```
<h:head>
    <title>Template</title>
    <ui:insert name="head" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <ui:include src="./topbar.xhtml" />
    <ui:include src="./menu.xhtml" />

    <div class="layout-main">
        <ui:insert name="content" />
    </div>
</h:body>
```

Comment: Do a clean buid and check the **deployed** war and the server startup log... several almost identical Q/A state so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested this very same component and it's working fine with Primefaces 6.1 (Maven).

However, as stated in [PrimeFaces's Showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/organigram.xhtml) this is a new component introduced on version 6.0.8.

My guess is that you just updated your PrimeFaces version for a newer one (6.1) but did not build correctly the project.

In this case, close your application servers, make a Maven clean and build
and re-deploy your application. Everything should work fine.

If the problem is not gone, then your project must have some configuration problem. I'd say you should start a new project and see if you still get any errors (probably not).

Comment: i was using 6.0 version, updated to 6.1 and the problem just appeared. Eclipse editor was encountering the tag. I updated the Maven Project, but when i did this, a lot of another problems came from nowhere. But worked after Update the project. Thanks!!